# SQL Error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int

Tags: sql-server-2008, varchar

I have a select statement that I want to include URL's from our staff directory.  The table that I'm using has the ID number that references the page within the directory.  To display the URL I'm adding:

```
a href="http://intranet' + per.DepartmentID +  '</a>' as 'Dept'
```

This will obviously generate

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '

Is there any way to to this in SQL? I have tried using CAST or REPLACE but I can't get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try why this
`SELECT 'a href="http://intranet' + CONVERT(varchar(20), DepartmentID) + '"' as Dept`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion above but error generated is'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. I'm using SQL Server 2005. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem of conversion, the hyperlink tag you generate is also malformed.

You should do this:

```
SELECT '<a href="http://intranet' + CAST(DepartmentID as VARCHAR) + '">The link name</a>' as Dept
```